# Add rows in a dataframe when a special character is encountered in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

My initial data looks like following :

```
ColA   ColB                 ColC
Sku1   Life/Personal        NA
Sku2   Children             NA 
Sku3   Grooming/Hair/Makeup NA
```

I want for ever slash ("/") in Col B, text after that should come in another row. For ex, above data should look like below :

```
ColA   ColB          ColC
Sku1   Life          NA
Sku1   Personal      NA
Sku2   Children      NA
Sku3   Grooming      NA
Sku3   Hair          NA
Sku3   Makeup        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

First split the values in column B by the delimiter '/'.

```
df['ColB'] = df['ColB'].str.split('/')
```

Then use `explode` to split the lists in column B into new rows.

```
df = df.explode('ColB')
```